Is a Semicha required for determining the status of a Safek Niddah
According to Halacha, is it required for a Rabbi to have semicha if he’s  determining the status of whether a woman is a niddah if she believes it’s a Safek? Or no, is a formal semicha not required for this?

I am not aware that modern-day smicha is a requirement for any ruling. Either the person knows halacha and has required experience, or not. Having scored the right answer on tests is one sign of knowledge, but not the only one. In Hilchot Niddah experience and shimush (learning from more experienced rabbis) as well as good sight are more important (there are highly knowledgeable and trained rabbis which stop answering Niddah shailot when their sense of colors change with age)

Questions concerning niddah can be determined by a Yoetzet Halacha. Please see the material below from the website of South Hampstead Synagogue, an orthodox synagogue (United Synagogue) in London NW3, UK:

Rebbetzen Lauren serves as the Yoetzet Halacha for South Hampstead
SHul.
Yoatzot halacha are women certified by a panel of orthodox rabbis to
be a resource for women with questions regarding Taharat Hamishpachah
(an area of Jewish Law that relates to marriage, sexuality and women’s
health). This role was devised to assist women who are more
comfortable discussing very personal issues with another woman.
South Hampstead is one of 25 communities worldwide that have a yoetzet
halacha. Lauren is happy to help any women who may welcome it from the
community and beyond. You can contact her by phone, whatsapp, email or
anonymously filling out the website form.

